# Is the highway mentioned in Isaiah a literal highway?

Tags: exegesis, isaiah

Isaiah refers several times to a "highway" that will be built.  Particularly, in [Isaiah 35:8-10 (NASB)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2035:8-10&version=NASB) he writes:

> A highway will be there, a roadway,
>
> And it will be called the Highway of Holiness.
>
> The unclean will not travel on it,
>
> But it will be for him who walks that way,
>
> And fools will not wander on it.
>
> No lion will be there,
>
> Nor will any vicious beast go up on it;
>
> These will not be found there.
>
> But the redeemed will walk there,
>
> And the ransomed of the LORD will return
>
> And come with joyful shouting to Zion,
>
> With everlasting joy upon their heads.
>
> They will find gladness and joy,
>
> And sorrow and sighing will flee away.

The commentary I'm reading assumed that this was a literal highway, but it seems like it could be a metaphor for Jesus, or perhaps Christianity:

> Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life; no one comes to the Father but through Me." - [John 14:6 (NASB)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:6&version=NASB)

Is this view supported by any scholarly work, and would a figurative interpretation of the highway fit poorly with other references to the highway by Isaiah?

Comment: Probably better at Biblical Hermeneutics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a Baptist perspective

We studied this in our Sunday School. In our studies we also assume it is a literal highway, that will exist but it is *also a figurative "picture" for walking with Christ in salvation.

Scripture contains many passages that are both literal and metaphorical. I'll stop at one example, though there are many: The priests in the Old Testament literally sacrificed animals, and we believe that these served both as a *temporary* covering for sin in O.T. times, but they were also a picture (or preview) of the coming Savior and the sacrifice He would ultimately make.

Comment: Sorry, I edited your post a little but the He was left as "he" and now I can't change it because its only one letter.